# Why is Tomcat refusing a connection from my other server?

Tags: php, http, tomcat

I have server A making a request to server B. I've tried both php's file_get_contents and curl; both refuse the connection. I'm trying to connect to a tomcat application on server B.

The connection *does* work if I make a request to google.com, or to another application on server B that is not in the Tomcat application.

This leads me to believe there's something specific to my tomcat installation that is rejecting the request from server A. Thoughts? Any more info I can provide to help with the problem?

Is there a way to whitelist my server A in tomcat so the connection is accepted? Or as a last resort how would I accept all requests?

**Edit:**  I also wanted to add that the connection to server B works just fine when I'm connecting from my local development machine.

Comment: What exactly is the error status/message? Doesn't it simply require a login or session or a valid UA?

Comment: file_get_content says "failed to open stream: Connection refused". How would I give it a session?

Comment: Is Tomcat anyway up and running and serving to the web? I.e. you're able to access it by a webbrowser? As per your edit, it sounds much like as Tomcat is running at your local machine and you're using `http://localhost` to connect it from the PHP host. Are you sure that you didn't make this mistake?

Comment: I wonder if it could be the content type, I'm using text/jsonp

Comment: Steve, text/jsonp shouldn't cause an error like that.  Do you have a shell on server A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test from server A to google.com or other apps on server B probably use port 80.  Many firewalls don't allow traffic on strange ports like 8089.

If you can't change the firewall rule to allow access to serverB:8089, I think the right way to do it is to proxy the request through the server B web server.  So server A would request "serverB:80/yourproxyurl" and the web server on server B would talk to the tomcat server on localhost, and output the response.

This is what [Tomcat Connectors](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Connectors) are for, as I understand it.

Comment: YES! The port number was the problem! I changed it to 591 (another official HTTP port) and it works perfectly! Thank you!